# Python sum values within nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, sum

For my first actual project, I am attempting to create a simple incremental game that runs in the Python IDLE. I have come across an issue where I need to get the sum of multiple values within nested dictionaries and am stuck.

Here is the dictionary that I am working with:

```
clickers = {
'': None,
'wooden_sword': {
    'owned': 5,
    'power': 1,
    'price': 5,
    },
'iron_sword': {
    'owned': 10,
    'power': 2.5,
    'price': 10,
    },
}
```

I am wondering if it would be possible to get the sum of just the `owned` values and save it to a variable.

The key `wooden_sword`'s `owned` value is equal to 5, and the key `iron_sword`'s `owned` value is equal to 10, I would like to sum those values and save them to a variable equal to their solution.

Comment: You can..but you have to specify the depth of nesting of dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
sum_ = 0
for k,v in clickers.items():
    if v:        # to ignore None 
        try:     # this to avoid key error
            sum_ += v['owned']
        except:
            pass
print(sum_)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done this way.

```
total = 0
for key ,value in clickers.items():
  if value and 'owned' in value.keys():
    total += value['owned']
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sum` function with a generator expression:

```
sum(d['owned'] for d in clickers.values() if d)
```

This returns:

```
15
```